# Implicit not found for partially applied type

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless, partially-applied-type

While this problem was caught in code using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) and [kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector), this behavior could be reproduced without them.

Suppose I have simple typeclass for reifying typeclass instances with incomplete implementation (mirror of [`LiftAll`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/eec3d55d1840a2ab31efedc9f8badefd6a49f5f9/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L2817)).

```
sealed trait LiftAll1[F[_], In] {
  type Out
  def instances: Out
}

object LiftAll1 {
  type Aux[F[_], In0, Out0] = LiftAll1[F, In0] {type Out = Out0}
  implicit def unit[F[_]]: Aux[F, Unit, Unit] = new LiftAll1[F, Unit] {
    type Out = Unit
    def instances = Unit
  }
}
```

And some very simple type class to test it

```
sealed class FirstIs[M, T]
object FirstIs {
  implicit def firstIs[M, D]: FirstIs[M, (M, D)] = new FirstIs
}
```

Things are ok if I'll try to apply `FirstIs` partially via alias, and get instance via `LiftAll1`

```
type FirstIsInt[D] = FirstIs[Int, D]
implicitly[LiftAll1[FirstIsInt, Unit]]
```

But inlined partial type application leads to compilation error

```
implicitly[LiftAll1[({type lambda[x] = FirstIs[Int, x]})#lambda, Unit]]
//Error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: LiftAll1[[x]FirstIs[Int,x],Unit]
```

How partially applied typeclasses could be found in such situations?

Comment: Are you using `-Ypartial-unification` on 2.12 or 2.11 typelevel scala?

Comment: @Reactormonk Somehow I forgot to add this option in that project. Thank you. Problem is solved.

Comment: @Odomontois you should answer the question and mark it correct ... it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Reactormonk suggested, the compiler [was brought to its senses](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2712) with following line in the `build.sbt`

```
scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"
```

After that original piece of code, which is close to

```
import shapeless._, ops.hlist._

LiftAll[FirstIs[Int, ?], HNil]
```

was succesfully compiled

AFAIK problem was in scala compiler incapability to understand `FirstIs[Int,_]` as `F[_]`in supplied `implicit def` without direct type alias . Fortunately this was fixed in latest scala implementations.